# Skip Coffeescript tests depending on software version

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a coffeescript file called `archive.spec.coffee`.

It begins with:

```
describe 'Archive', ->
```

and all tests are within the describe.

I want to check for a software version using a http call and depending on what that is, I'd like to either execute or skip the tests.

I think I need to do something like this but so far it isn't working:

```
req = https.get {host: "https://path/to/endpoint"}

if(req.version == 1.2.3)
  this.skip
else
  describe 'Archive', ->
```

Can anybody tell me how to correctly do this?

**Additional info**

I've came up with this:

```
beforeEach ->
  req = request.get {
    url: 'https://path/to/endpoint', 
    auth: {
      user: 'admin',
      pass: 'password'
    },
    json: true
  }, 
  (err, res, body) ->
    version = body.responseData.devices[0].versions[0].version
    if (version.indexOf('1.2.3') == -1)
      done()
    else
      this.skip()

describe 'Archive', ->
```

My problem now is that if version is 1.2.3, `version.indexOf('1.2.3')` returns 0, the `else` is entered but the tests are not skipped.

**Latest update**

Now I've come up with this:

```
before (done) ->
  req = request.get {
    url: 'https://path/to/endpoint', 
    auth: {
      user: 'admin',
      pass: 'password'
    },
    json: true
  }, 
  (err, res, body) ->
    version = body.responseData.devices[0].versions[0].version
    if (version.indexOf('1.2.3') != -1)
      skip = true
      done()
    else
      done()

describe 'Archive', ->

  it 'my_test', ->
    if (skip)
      this.skip()
```

If I test this with version 1.2.3 I can see that the skip is set to true in the before function. done() returns to my_test but `if (skip)` is `false`. Obviously this is because `skip` is set to true in a different function. How do I get it so that the before returns the value of skip to my test?

Comment: This sounds more like a problem solved with environment variables rather than a HTTP call. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Possibly. Could you elaborate on how that might be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a json formatted config file so I added a `version` key which takes an environment variable containing the version. Once in the config I can then use it as I like.